# Android: Change Activity from SurfaceView

Tags: android, canvas, android-activity, 2d

I am making a game with canvas. I need to make it so when the game has won it will change the activity but this can only be done in an Activity file. 
So my game works like this: It starts in MainActivity.class then creates the canvas and sets it as its view.

MainAcitivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MainGamePanel game;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // set our MainGamePanel as the View
    game = new MainGamePanel(this, 1);
    setContentView(game);

}
}
```

MainGamePanel.java:

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public MainGamePanel(Context context, int lvl) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    Level = lvl;
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    ball = new com.csdevelopers.canvas.sprite.Ball(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball),
            100, 100);
    if (Level == 1) {
        lvl1 = new lvl1(context);
    }

    public void checkWon1(){
    if(lvl1.checkWon(ball)){
        // change Activity HERE!!!
    }
}

}
```

So in the public void checkWon1() i am not able to change the Activity because the intent cannot be called from a non-Activity class. How can i can back to the MainActivity and tell it to change the Activity?

Comment if you need it more explained.

Answer (score 1):

You change it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getContext(), ActivityToChange.class);
((Activity) getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your setup is any like mine try

the below code will go in the surfaceView class

```
private void passToMainActivity()  {
    ((MainActivity) context).callMe(dead);
}
```

the next code goes in your activity class that creates the surfaceView class

```
public void callMe(boolean dead) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

depending if you have a 3rd java class that has a second thread, you may need to pause the thread by

```
suspend();
```